# I am trying to learn how to import and use a class from another file (that I made). Why isn't my output showing 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

ClassFile.py

```
class Stuff:
    number3 = 0

    def __init__(self, number1, number2):
        self.number1 = number1
        self.number2 = number2
        global number3
        number3 = number1 + number2
```

Main.py

```
from ClassFile import Stuff

ob = Stuff(3, 4)
print(ob.number3)
```

The output of the main.py is 0 shouldn't it be 7?

Comment: Hint: the problem is `global number3`. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the self when assigning the sum to number3.
You do not need the global variable as i can see.

ClassFile.py

```
class Stuff:
    def __init__(self, number1, number2):
        self.number1 = number1
        self.number2 = number2
        self.number3 = number1 + number2
```

Main.py

```
from ClassFile import Stuff

ob = Stuff(3, 4)
print(ob.number3)
```

Comment: Can I get some insight as to why my code did not work?

Comment: If you run your code  and print(number3) you will get 7, this happens because you changed globally the variable value, and it stood 0 inside the class.

Comment: This is why print(ob.number3) = 0 and print(number3) = 7, variables scopes.
Check more here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword